# Reverse substring

Tags: sql, substring, reverse, charindex

I am trying to extract some characters from a string.
For Example in (316409953_ND_02142022_000001.pdf) I need the characters after the last underscore _ and before the "."
Answer: 000001
@test = 316409953_ND_02142022_000001.pdf

I have tried:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(test),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(test))+1,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(test)+1)))
```

I need help with the last part of substring. First error I am getting is "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'fdp.100000_22024120_DN_359904613' to data type int."
Secondly I need it to pick only after the last "_"
Please guide or let me know if there's another way to do this.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (REVERSE etc are product specific functions.=

Answer (score 0):

This *looks* like SQL Server.

On that assumption, and using the single example value, you can try the follolwing:

```
declare @test varchar(50) = '316409953_ND_02142022_000001.pdf'

select @test OriginalValue,
   ParseName(Right(@test, CharIndex('_',Reverse(@test))-1),2) ExtractedValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

it isn't pretty but it does the job ;P

```
declare @str varchar(200) = '316409953_ND_02142022_000001.pdf'
declare @tempStr varchar(200)= (select SUBSTRING(@str,LEN(@str) + 2 - CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@str)),LEN(@str)))
set @tempStr = SUBSTRING(@tempStr,1,CHARINDEX('.',@tempStr) - 1)
select @tempStr
```